# Can't get QGraphicsEllipseItem() to display

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I can't seem to get a QGraphicsEllipseItem to show up in my view. I am attempting to use it in combination with a QGraphicsLineItem:

```
# Instantiate the line object:
self.profileLine = QGraphicsLineItem()
self.profileLine.setPen(QPen(Qt.yellow, 1.0))
self.profileLine.setLine(self.StartX, self.StartY, self.StopX, self.StopY)
self.scene.addItem(self.profileLine)

# Instantiate the circle:
self.profileStopHandle = QGraphicsEllipseItem()
self.profileStopHandle.setPen(QPen(Qt.yellow, 1.0))
self.profileStopHandle.setRect(self.StopX, self.StopY, 50, 50)
self.scene.addItem(self.profileStopHandle)
```

Later, in my mouse move event, I determine the current mouse coordinates, assign them to StopX/StopY and redraw the line from the start point to the new stop point as well as draw the ellipse around the new stop point:

```
self.profileLine.setLine(self.StartX, self.StartY, self.StopX, self.StopY)
self.profileStopHandle.setPos(self.StopX, self.StopY)
```

The line shows up fine and behaves just as it should, but no matter what I cannot seem to get the ellipse to draw. I know the point coordinates I'm passing to it are correct because they are the same ones I'm using for the line. The ellipse just never appears as if it was never created in the first place. What am I doing wrong here (it must be something very basic)? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Z-value (amateur mistake). I brought the ellipse to the foreground and now it is visible:

```
self.profileStopHandle.setZValue(self.sceneImage.zValue() + 1.0)
```